# SSRS - Show values from individual rows in a single row

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Could someone please help me figure out how to combine Date values from separate rows into a single row where the Date values now appear in separate columns?

TABLE Activities

```
Activity_Code |Job_ID |Description   |Date 
S001          |PR201  |Start Date    |24/03/20 
S001          |PR202  |Start Date    |16/04/20
S002          |PR202  |Finished Date |16/06/20
S002          |PR201  |Finished Date |12/05/20
S003          |PR201  |Reported Date |05/10/20
S004          |PR201  |Fabric. Date  |20/04/20  -- Not interested in reporting this activity
```

The result would look something like this

```
Job_ID |Start_Date |Finished_Date |Reported_Date
PR201  |24/03/20   |12/05/20      |02/10/20
PR202  |16/04/20   |16/06/20      |NULL (or blank)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select job_id,
       max(case when Description = 'Start Date' then date end) as start_date,
       max(case when Description = 'Finished Date' then date end) as finished_date,
       max(case when Description = 'Reported Date' then date end) as reported_date
from t
group by job_id;
```